# How did 'adumbrate' evolve to mean 'represent in outline'?

Tags: etymology

What's an intuitive derivation behind [ODO's definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adumbrate) that helps to remember its meaning?

> 1. **adumbrate** = [with object]
>   Represent in outline:
>
> [Etymonline for **adumbration**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adumbrate&searchmode=none): 1530s, from Latin adumbrationem (nominative adumbratio) "a sketch in shadow, sketch, outline," noun of action from past participle stem of adumbrare "to cast a shadow, overshadow, represent (a thing) in outline," from **ad-** "to" (see ad-) + **umbrare** "to cast in shadow," from PIE *andho- "blind, dark" (see umbrage).

My confusion arises from opposition between the clarity of an outline and haziness of a shadow. ODO's definitions 2 and 3 seem fitter, because they directly involve the idea of 'shadow'.

Comment: So your confusion arises from the fact you have never seen a clearly outlined shadow? They exist, and are extremely common in situations with a single light source, for instance _outside on a sunny day_. You can see places where the sunlight is blocked by objects, forming a very clear _outline_ of those objects on the ground.

Comment: I see your point: 'Ombrager' in French and 'adombrare' in Italian means to cover, conceal, obscurate. In English the meaning 'to sketch an outline' as that of a shadow (meaning to reveal rather than conceal) has actually gained currency.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows can be (indeed, usually are) crisp:

they are basically "accurate, but 'colourless / line drawings' of an object"

http://city-mouse-country-mouse.blogspot.fr/2012/09/september-shadows.html

[image]

It's funny that the high-tech analogy we'd use today would probably be something like "give me the mesh version!" (like, in a 3D game or movie, just the "mesh", the actual form, of the character, rather than all the rendering, colouring, etc etc.)

Comment: "Wireframe it!"

Comment: Think simple, think solid.

Comment: LOL so true Matt !  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the picture. Forget shadow – think silhouette. That is an outline of the object. So is a shadow, and an eclipse.

HTH.